# Block execution until condition

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, eventlet

I am using eventlet and have two main process running. One of the process acts as a producer and the other as consumer. The problem is that instead of using queue from eventlet package I want to use a db. 
Using queue I can simple pass (block=True) as argument and eventlet would take care of bloking execution of the consumer routine untill the producer puts something in queue. 
If I replace queue with db how do I efficiently implement blocking logic.

Comment: I think a simple lock will do the job. But why do you even want to use a database instead of a queue?

Comment: Untill now I am using eventlet.queue.LightQueue. The reason I am thinking of db is because my consumer also has to send somethink like a reply to the producer in some cases. I thought that a record in db would be a better for two way communication.

Comment: Then why not using two queue's? One for sending and one for replying?

Comment: I am considering all options. Also I would like to know how blocking logic is implemented in queues. using time.sleep every few seconds looks like an inefficient method. There should be some other better way to do it.

Comment: I found this page http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91820807.html maybe it will help. As far as i know all concurrency implementations do not use time.sleep. They use notify instead. That means that your waiting thread is sleeping until another thread wakes him up. Its just like waiting for an apointment. Your just waiting for someone to get (notify) you.

Comment: That helps even if it is not a direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for data in DB every N seconds. If nothing found - sleep.

UPDATE: or use Postgresql LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanism as shown in http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/12/01/postgresql-notifications-psycopg2-eventlet/

Comment: Polling approach has an issue of balance: either you sleep too much and waste time, either you sleep too less and waste CPU/network resources.

Comment: It's problem in theory only. Pulling DB every 100ms should be nothing for both DB and you server. If 100ms is too big latency, author of the question should ask why does he want to make queue in the database, when there are a lot of specialized solutions (RabbitMQ and others)

Comment: @AlexDvoretsky Your answers is definitely one of the methods commonly used for this problem. I was already aware of that although I had not mentioned it in my question. Queue or DB was definitely a thought in my mind(I have a lot more problems than I had mentioned in my initial question), but my actual intention was to find the most efficient method to implement blocking logic.

Comment: You said that you want to use db. There is no any _magic_ blocking on db. Thread (real or green) can block on socket I/O and special OS primitives like semaphore. With db there is only one way - pull it.

Comment: PostgreSQL has LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanism and advisory locks that could be used to implement efficient blocking. All databases have explicit table locks that could be used like: producer locks table and inserts a row when it's ready. Consumers lock table and select, then delete a row. It's actually a queue implemented with database as backend. So, again, ready solutions do the same thing but they're ready and tested.

Comment: @AlexDvoretsky Yes I did. I wanted to check with others before I conclude that it is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

For a background, you may wish to read this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

I'd recommend using socket connection between these two processes. You can easily send some data along with wake up signal that way. Please, note that TCP does not have notion of message (as in piece of information that is sent and delivered as a whole), so you'd have to implement a simple protocol to achieve that. I recommend tnetstring [1]. Other approach is to use ZeroMQ, because it provides messages. Eventlet features excellent support for both ways.

You may need transaction job semantics on producer/consumer, as in: any piece of data is either completely processed by some consumer or failed and will need repeated attempt or human attention. Then you really have to use some kind of database with transactions. There are ready solutions: Celery [2], beanstalk [3], pyres [4].

- [1] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tnetstring
- [2] http://celery.readthedocs.org/ I dislike it for being "django of task queues" [3], but it gets the job done and is probably best shot should you need a task queue. In this context, django is a synonim for being unnecessarily complicated, unable to focus on few clear problems, enterprise style creating jobs because it takes a lot of time and effort to learn the tool.
- [3] http://beanstalkapp.com/
- [4] https://github.com/binarydud/pyres